# Upload file to remote system (not server) using html POST method and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way to upload some file from one system and store it in another system connected to same network using HTML POST method and php such that there are 3 different systems involved [client (source), server (code will be here) and remote system (destination)]
Note: I am able to upload file from client to server

Comment: its possible. But you need to have plans for the security issues waiting to happen.

Comment: @Dwhitz:  At the end, the uploaded file should be present in remote system. With my current code, it is reaching server. So, i need a way to pass it to remote system from server.

Comment: @Akintunde : Ok, so can you let me know how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways

- Just post  to "file-server" and redirect back to "page"
- Upload to "page" and "page" is using any protocol you want to store the file somewhere else. rsync, ftp, or a http-post via curl etc.
- Build up a tunnel between the systems and mount the destination path so you can use the file-server as a normal directory on your page server

your question is not precise enough to give you a better answer.